# Swift: How to notify when purchase is complete

Tags: ios, swift, storekit

I have a `SKPaymentTransactionObserver` checking when purchase is complete

```
extension IAPService: SKPaymentTransactionObserver {
func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
    for transaction in transactions {
        print(transaction.transactionState.status(), transaction.payment.productIdentifier)
        if transaction.transactionState.status() == "purchased" {
            // Pro Purchased
        }
        switch transaction.transactionState {
        case .purchasing: break
        default: queue.finishTransaction(transaction)
        }
    }
}
}
```

How can I hide an object on the `ViewController`, purchased from when purchase is complete

Comment: Check this example out: https://github.com/bobbymay/In-App-Purchase

Comment: Have you read the [In-App Purchase Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH1-SW1)?

Comment: @rmaddy Yes I have, but I can't find anything telling me how to get notified when purchase is complete. I want to be able to run a function the second the transaction state is purchased

Comment: Read the section on implementing the delegate method you have in your question (I think it's in Objective-C in the guide). It shows all of the different transaction states you need to handle.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. `.transactionState` has several states, but you are only looking at `purchasing`? What about `purchased` and `failed`?

Comment: @dfd They are run trough default. Any idea how I can handle some objects on the view controller, when the state is purchased? So that the user don’t have to re-enter the viewcontroller

Comment: Without more understanding of the full code, I'd guess @rmaddy is correct - implement a delegate.

Comment: Are you trying to do somthing like this? UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.rootViewController?.view.viewWithTag(5000).alpha = 0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a closure in your IAPService class:

```
var productDidPurchased: (() -> Void)?
```

Then in your extension you can use it in this way:

```
switch transaction.transactionState {
    case .purchasing: 
        break
    case .purchased:
        productDidPurchased?()
    default:
        queue.finishTransaction(transaction)
}
```

Then in your ViewController to retrieve it:

```
IAPService.shared.productDidPurchased = { 
    [weak self] in 
    //you will receive a callback when the product is purchased and can hide your view here 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. When I try to implement this code I get an error saying "Value of type 'IAPService' has no member 'productDidPurchased'"

Comment: IAPService is your class to manage in app purchases or you are using a library?

Comment: Just had to restart Xcode and this worked great! Thanks a lot

Comment: @FrancescoDeliro you are the BEST!!!! Thx you for this answer!!! It still works with SwiftUI!!!

Comment: Happy to help! :)